# Open-source/freeware testing tool for Set-Top Box

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, embedded

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-top_box) a **set-top box** (STB) is:

> an information appliance device that generally contains a tuner and connects to a television set and an external source of signal, turning the source signal into content in a form that can then be displayed on the television screen or other display device. Set-top boxes can also enhance source signal quality. They are used in cable television and satellite television systems, as well as other uses.

Apart from [STB-Tester](http://stb-tester.com), is there any other open-source or freeware STB-testing tool available?

I have searched a lot on google but haven't found anything other than STB-Tester. I earlier posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099254/set-top-box-open-source-freeware-testing-tool) in Stack Overflow, but couldn't get any answer, so hoping posting here may get some replies.

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099254/set-top-box-open-source-freeware-testing-tool

Comment: Why are you after something that isn't stb-tester?  Is there a feature missing that you need or some other issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you give up on the open source and free [RT-RK](http://www.rt-rk.com/) (or [Black Box Testing](http://www.bbt.rs/) I'm not sure who's who) has a set top boxes testing solution.

The demo was impressive, we never got beyond it though (we developed an in house solution)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I know of RT-RK/BBT (they appear to be same), they even have a free partial demo version, that has a virtual remote, and can generate scripts. But it doesn't appear to do much. 

Could you give me an approx. estimate on time (in hrs or mnths or years) did it take to you to build that solution. 

And if it was In-house, it must be specific to your own STB. Do u think (based on your experience) that a fully capable solution (answer to all testing needs of STB) for all possible (major) STB manufacturers is possible? 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because most of the STB testing solution in market seem to be testing only functionalities, i.e. Black box testing. which can be done independent of platform .

Comment: Development took about 1 man/year with backed up by aa generous budget (e.g. test equipment) and support teams (e.g. the developing test framework itself).
We are developing a related product, not a STB so I can't really answer your questions.

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks for giving an estimate of time. Need to plan accordingly then. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I heard that Motorola consists a test tool team to develop test tool for STB last year. Not sure what is going on so far yet.

In order to develop the test tool specific to your STB, the best way is to build communication protocol between your test framework with STB so that we can have two ways communication back and forth computer and STB. If we just control the key press for STB, that is the one way test and we don't have information back from STB. As we know, we have different types of STB and different STB may need different languages to write the test program. That is why it is so hard to find a universal test tools to test different STB.